# convert double quote array values to single quote in php

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $newArray=[];
    $arr=["1660109707.jpg","1660109715.png","1660201812.jpg","1660201843.jpg","1660208040.jpg"];
    foreach($arr as $ar)
    {
        $newArray[]=str_replace('"', "'", trim($ar,'"')); 

    }
    $newArray=json_encode($newArray);
    dd($newArray);
```

I tried the above code. but it still outputs "`["1660109707.jpg","1660109715.png","1660201812.jpg","1660201843.jpg","1660208416.jpg"]"`

espected

```
['1660109707.jpg','1660109715.png','1660201812.jpg','1660201843.jpg','1660208416.jpg']
```

Comment: `foreach($arr as $ar)` makes no sense to begin with - your `$arr` does _not_ contain an array, it contains a string value.

Comment: Before posting code, please test it. The posted code won't work at all, since `$arr` is a string, not an array. You need to json decode the data first. However, that won't give you the quotes (since they are a part of the JSON structure, not your values.) If you were to change it from double to single quotes in the original string, it won't be valid JSON anymore (and will be useless)

Comment: And besides that, trying to use `json_encode` for this, makes little sense to begin with - the JSON format _requires_ that string values be put into double quotes, so it is pointless to expect that this would ever get you anything else.

Comment: @CBroe even if he didn't specify the usefulness of the desired results, it is still pretty clear what OP wants. maybe it is for a weird js editor that accepts only simple quotes or he think js doesnt accept simple quotes.

Comment: You should add how you are using the "expected" results in your application to your question. I'm positive that the core issue is there because json format is a powerfull and perfect tool.

Comment: @N69S I did not question what they want or what for; I simply pointed out that trying to use `json_encode` to _get_ the desired result, makes little sense to begin with - because that will always get you double quotes as string delimiters.

Comment: @N69S justified _perhaps_ if it was actually used the way you do in your answer. My explanation was supposed to make clear to the OP here that their _"but it still outputs"_ doesn't actually justify the use of the word "but" there to begin with ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that expected result, you can replace the double quotes after the json encoding

```
$arr = ["1660109707.jpg","1660109715.png","1660201812.jpg","1660201843.jpg","1660208040.jpg"];
$jsonText=json_encode($arr);

//$jsonText = str_replace("'", "\'", $jsonText); //this is to replace the "inside text" quotes to escaped ones.It is not needed in your example
$notJsonText = str_replace("\"", "'", $jsonText);
dd($notJsonText);
```

Keep in mind that the resulting text in no longer a valid json format since json requires that string be encapsulated by double quotes `"`

By the way, these two arrays are equivalent

```
$arr1 = ["1660109707.jpg"];
$arr2 = ['1660109707.jpg'];

dd($arr1 === $arr2); //true
```